# MySQL Get Different services for each IP

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
|    **IP**   | **PORT** | **SERVICE** | **VERSION** |
|:-------:|:----:|:-------:|:-------:|
| 1.2.3.4 |  80  |   HTTP  |   1.1   |
| 1.2.3.4 |  443 |   HTTP  |   1.2   |
| 1.2.3.4 |  25  |   SMTP  |   a     |
| 2.3.4.5 |  80  |   HTTP  |   1.2   |
| 2.3.4.5 |  443 |   HTTP  |   1.2   |
| 2.3.4.5 |  25  |   SMTP  |   a     |
| 3.4.5.6 |  25  |   SMTP  |   b     |
| 3.4.5.6 |  443 |   HTTP  |   1.2   |
| 0.0.0.1 |  25  |   SMTP  |   b     |
| 0.0.0.2 |  443 |   HTTP  |   1.2   |
```

And I want to get a list of the different services by port, service and version between some of the IPs, for example the result for the IPs 1.2.3.4, 2.3.4.5 and 3.4.5.6 should be similar to the following: As the rest of the services on those IPs are the same port, service and version.

Different services for IPs 1.2.3.4, 2.3.4.5 and 3.4.5.6:

```
|    IP   | PORT | SERVICE | VERSION |
|:-------:|:----:|:-------:|:-------:|
| 1.2.3.4 |  80  |   HTTP  |   1.1   |
| 1.2.3.4 |  25  |   SMTP  |   a     |
| 2.3.4.5 |  80  |   HTTP  |   1.2   |
| 2.3.4.5 |  25  |   SMTP  |   a     |
| 3.4.5.6 |  25  |   SMTP  |   b     |
```

Not sure how to get them on a Query.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Similar... Tell us what you want exactly.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the difference between three sets of data.

Comment: Your description and your sample data don't match.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  If I understand correctly, you care more about *ports* than *services*.  If so:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.ip in ('1.2.3.4', '2.3.4.5', '3.4.5.6') and
      t.port in (select t2.port from t t2 where t2.ip in ('1.2.3.4', '2.3.4.5', '3.4.5.6'));
```

Comment: And different versions of the service.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, the requirement is to group by ip and service.

```
select t.*
from t where t.ip in ('1.2.3.4', '2.3.4.5', '3.4.5.6') 
group by ip,service;
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try by applying group's on IP and SERVICE columns.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Complete answers please.